# Combining array of arrays based on first element

Tags: ruby

I have an array of arrays, the inner array containing an item number and a quantity:

```
array = [[a, 4], [b, 6], [d, 4], [a, 6], [b, 8]]
```

I want to combine them so that each item is listed only once, with the sum of its quantities:

```
[[a, 10], [b, 14], [d, 4]
```

What is the easiest way for me to do this?

Comment: I am confused. What does this have to do with Rails?

Comment: It's the framework I'm using. I'm however guessing that's your way of saying "This should be in ruby'.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". We'd like to see evidence of your effort. What did you try? Did you search and not find anything? Did you find stuff but it didn't help? Did you try writing code? If not, why? If so, what is the smallest code example that shows what you tried and why didn't it work? Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to contribute. Next time I'll include my failed attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
array = [[:a, 4], [:b, 6], [:d, 4], [:a, 6], [:b, 8]]
array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(k, v), memo| memo[k] += v }
#=> {:a=>10, :b=>14, :d=>4}
```

You can convert the result into an array (by simply calling `to_a`), but as for me, a hash is more suitable here.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I tend to just always use arrays out of habit but a hash is clearly better here, many thanks.

Comment: Don't use arrays out of habit. Hashes are faster for any lookups, and arrays are useful for queues and lists, so it's important to use each for what they're good for. Failing to do that results in convoluted code that works around the bad design choice.

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear to me what this has to do with Rails. The Ruby solution is just:

```
array.group_by(&:first).map {|key, values| [key, values.sum(&:last)] }
#=> [[a, 10], [b, 14], [d, 4]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As I only use ruby when using rails I sometimes interchange them (wrongly I know), and appreciate this is in the wrong section. Thanks again.

Comment: And just FYI - your answer doesn't work in plain ruby as you state, and is in fact a rails exclusive answer.

Comment: I have no idea why you would think that. I tested it in plain Ruby. In fact, I don't even have Rails installed, so I wouldn't even know whether or not it works in Rails.

Comment: Another commenter pointed it out. It appears I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity:

```
array.each_with_object({}) do |e, acc|
  acc.merge!([e].to_h) { |_, v1, v2| v1 + v2 }
end
```